# Postgres/Rails - what is the most efficient way to use GIN indexes and other filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing

I have a Postgres database table called "statements" that consists of 1.4 million records -- each of which contains a "statement_text" field on which I've implemented full text search using a GIN index. My ballpark guess is that each "statement_text" contains somewhere around 50 words (so maybe 250 characters on average).

I've created a simple search engine, using Rails, that utilizes the GIN index, which is quite fast most of the time. My problem is that I'd like it to be even faster, and the easiest way to do this is to filter by some of the other fields in the "statements" table -- one of which, "casefile," contains about 6,500 unique values and another of which, "speaker," contains about 8,000 unique values. (I've created b-tree indices on both.)

This should work in practice because users searching the "statement_text" field are often interested in results from only a very small subset of the "casefile" or "speaker" values. The problem is, using EXPLAIN, I've noticed that Postgres often either abandons the GIN index entirely or combines it (seemingly) inefficiently with my normal b-tree indices on the "casefile" and "speaker" fields. This can result in very long query times.

To prevent this from happening, I changed the query so it always has only one "where" condition -- the "statement_text" query term, thus ensuring the GIN index will be used -- and then I `pluck` that field along with "casefile" and "speaker", so I can iterate through the resulting array and filter out all the ones I don't need immediately after the query finishes. But this seems like a highly inefficient way to query the database, since I'm throwing out most of the returned results immediately after I'm finished querying.

My (rather open-ended) questions are:

1) Has anyone else run into a problem in getting GIN index to play nicely with b-tree indices? As much as I've tried to read up on this, both here on SO and elsewhere, I'm still not sure I grasp whether GIN and b-tree indices ever really work in combination on the back end.

2) Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same outcome than I'm doing currently?

Thank you very much. As a relative newcomer to coding, I find SO immensely helpful.

Jay

UPDATE: Adding in some EXPLAIN statements to demonstrate.

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "statements".* FROM "statements"  WHERE (to_tsvector('simple', statement_text) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'hello'))
                                           QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on statements  (cost=373.48..4349.24 rows=2243 width=247)
   Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, statement_text) @@ '''hello'''::tsquery)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_statement_text  (cost=0.00..373.36 rows=2243 width=0)
     Index Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, statement_text) @@ '''hello'''::tsquery)
```

Now with an extra condition:

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "statements".* FROM "statements"  WHERE (to_tsvector('simple', statement_text) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'hello') and casefile_id in (12,563,876,4303,1120,422,654,13,988,335))
                                                                                  QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on statements  (cost=417.81..425.80 rows=4 width=247)
   Recheck Cond: ((casefile_id = ANY ('{12,563,876,4303,1120,422,654,13,988,335}'::integer[])) AND (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, statement_text) @@ '''hello'''::tsquery))
   ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=417.81..417.81 rows=4 width=0)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_statements_on_casefile_id  (cost=0.00..44.40 rows=2363 width=0)
           Index Cond: (casefile_id = ANY ('{12,563,876,4303,1120,422,654,13,988,335}'::integer[]))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_statement_text  (cost=0.00..373.36 rows=2243 width=0)
           Index Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, statement_text) @@ '''hello'''::tsquery)
```

And adding in another:

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "statements".* FROM "statements"  WHERE (to_tsvector('simple', statement_text) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'hello') and casefile_id in (12,563,876,4303,1120,422,654,13,988,335) and speaker_name in ('Seth Waxman'))
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on statements  (cost=46.70..48.70 rows=1 width=247)
   Recheck Cond: (((speaker_name)::text = 'Seth Waxman'::text) AND (casefile_id = ANY ('{12,563,876,4303,1120,422,654,13,988,335}'::integer[])))
   Filter: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, statement_text) @@ '''hello'''::tsquery)
   ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=46.70..46.70 rows=1 width=0)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_statements_on_speaker_name_and_person_role_id  (cost=0.00..2.25 rows=109 width=0)
               Index Cond: ((speaker_name)::text = 'Seth Waxman'::text)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_statements_on_casefile_id  (cost=0.00..44.40 rows=2363 width=0)
               Index Cond: (casefile_id = ANY ('{12,563,876,4303,1120,422,654,13,988,335}'::integer[]))
```

Filtering by just speaker_name:

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "statements".* FROM "statements"  WHERE (to_tsvector('simple', statement_text) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'hello') and speaker_name in ('Seth Waxman'))
                                                        QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using index_statements_on_speaker_name_and_person_role_id on statements  (cost=0.09..217.67 rows=1 width=247)
   Index Cond: ((speaker_name)::text = 'Seth Waxman'::text)
   Filter: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, statement_text) @@ '''hello'''::tsquery)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show an EXPLAIN ANALYZE demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielVérité. Just added some examples.